# Error installing cordova windows 7

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I have some problem while i started to install cordova
I use windows 7
I run npm install -g cordova in administrator mode

Attempting to install cordova as per the docs, gives the following

```html
$ npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 103.245.222.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sridharanp\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Issue with your network connectivity https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10062

Comment: run `npm config delete proxy` and then install cordova

Comment: @Divyesh Savaliya tried not working